# View CGM file on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, image-viewer

How to view CGM ([Computer Graphics Metafile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics_Metafile)) files on Linux?

Opening a .cgm file with Inkscape (after installing python-uniconvertor) fails due to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820748).

Must be free.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) is a command line based set of utilities including the [display](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php) command that supports 100s of file formats including CGM format.

- Free gatis & open source.
- cross platform including Linux, OS-X & Windows.
- lots of other facilities.

You may also need to install [ralcgm](http://www.agocg.ac.uk/train/cgm/ralcgm.htm) for it to work correctly.

Comment: That's what I tried first, unfortunately it did not managed to display my .cgm... Thanks for the ralcgm tip, it does not seem to have .deb nor .rpm packages but I will try to install it manually.

Comment: The link appears to not working for Linux binary